# yodeya.com down

Tags: bug, status-completed

Although I can access the main site by its URL [`http://judaism.stackexchange.com`](http://judaism.stackexchange.com), I can't, since yesterday, access it by its URLs [`http://yodeya.com`](http://yodeya.com), [`http://mi.yodeya.com`](http://mi.yodeya.com), or [`http://miyodeya.com`](http://miyodeya.com): the server never responds. (I've flushed my local DNS cache.)

(Note that there was a DoS attack on Stack Exchange yesterday; however, I don't know whether this is related, and AFAIK everything else is back up and running.)

Comment: [`http://mi.yodeya.com`](http://mi.yodeya.com) works for me, but the others don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just pushed through a DNS change that should fix this soon.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: All of them work for me now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Working for me now too.